# Unable to have consecutive dots for each x-axis category in a dotplot

Tags: python, visualization

Trying to replicate a dot plot, but I am unable to have dots arranged consecutively like in the original figure. My dots are all over the place.

Original:
[image: Original]

My attempt:
[image: My attempt]

```
`###Data Visualization
# Import data
merged_df = pd.read_excel("part1_data_output.xlsx")

# Define income groups
income_groups = merged_df["Income Group"].unique()

# Group merged_df by income group
grouped_df = merged_df.groupby("Income Group")

# Set up plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
dot_color = (31/255, 58/255, 112/255, 1)

# Set the x-tick locations
x_ticks = np.arange(len(income_groups)) + 1
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks)

# Set the x-tick labels
ax.set_xticklabels(income_groups)

# Invert the x-axis
ax.invert_xaxis()

# Set the y-axis label and limit
ax.set_ylabel("Number of Reforms")
ax.set_ylim(0,25)

# Plot the data
for i, (group, df) in enumerate(grouped_df):
    x_vals = np.linspace(i+1-0.2, i+1+0.2, len(df))
    x_offsets = np.random.uniform(low=-0.1, high=0.1, size=len(df))
    x_vals += x_offsets
    y_vals = df["Number of Reforms"].tolist()
    ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, color=dot_color, s=40)

# Set the title
ax.set_title("FIGURE 2.3 | IMPLEMENTING GENDER REFORM IS NOT DEPENDENT ON INCOME LEVEL")

# Remove the spines except for the bottom and left ones
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["bottom"].set_linewidth(0.5)
ax.spines["left"].set_linewidth(0.5)

# Save the plot as png
plt.savefig('plot.png', dpi=600)

# Show the plot
plt.show()`
```

I tried fixing space, but it didn't work. I